Reference Request: Probability-and-Convexity Statement
I can prove the following statement, but it would be even better to have a reference I can cite. Does anyone know where this (or a generalization) is proven?

Proposition. Let $0 \leq b \leq a$, and for a random variable $X$ supported on $[0,a]$, let
$$\mathbb{E}_b[X] = \mathbb{E}[X \mathbb{1}_{X \leq b}].$$
Suppose $X$ is such a random variable with
$$(*) \ \ \mathbb{E}[X] \geq \alpha \text{ and } \mathbb{E}_b[X] \geq \beta,$$
where $0 \leq \beta \leq \alpha$. Then the random variable $Z$ with
$$\mathbb{P}(Z=b) = \beta/b, \mathbb{P}(Z=a) = (\alpha-\beta)/a, \text{ and } \mathbb{P}(Z=0) = 1 - (\mathbb{P}(Z=b) + \mathbb{P}(Z=a)),$$
satisfies $(*)$ (with equality) and, for any convex $g : [0,a] \to \mathbb{R}$ with $g(a) \leq g(0)$,
$$\mathbb{E}[g(Z)] \geq \mathbb{E}[g(X)].$$

Please add your proof here in the OP or as an answer. Then, you can cite this page after members confirm that your proof is correct (in link Cite below your question you can see how to cite this question ).

Creative idea, thank you for commenting! In my case, if I would have to cite a stack exchange post, it would be better to just keep the proof in the paper. And, might this be a (corollary of a) classical result?

It is a bit early to decide. After evaluating the result, a better decision can be made. If the result is not easily obtained from the existing theorems, I recommend that you include it in your paper and also cite this page in case that other poofs are presented by members.
